# Property 'emailAddress' does not exist on type 'BaseModel'.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a feature that calls the api from the service , Now I wanted to do for each on the res.items and check the emailAddress but I cant loop through it and I am receiving an error Property 'emailAddress' does not exist on type 'BaseModel'.ts which I dont understand on why.

What seem to be the issue that causes this one ? why is that the for each not working ? Any ideaS?

this is the sample data from the _transactionUserPageEvent
[image]

#Component A service

```
getUserProfileTableDropdown(
    id: number,
    page: number,
    pageSize: number,
    searchString: string,
    sortKey: string[],
    sortOrder: string[]
  ): Observable<PagedModel> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('id', id.toString())
      .set('page', page.toString())
      .set('pageSize', pageSize.toString())
      .set('searchString', searchString)
      .set('sortKey', JSON.stringify(sortKey) || '')
      .set('sortOrder', JSON.stringify(sortOrder) || '');
    return this.httpRequestService.get<PagedModel>(
      `${apiBaseUrl}/table/profiles`,
      params
    );
  }
```

#Component A TS Code

```
private _transactionUserPageEvent() {
    this.isTransactionUserLoading = true;
    this.transactionUserTable.data = [];
    this._userProfileService.getUserProfileTableDropdown(
      this.accountId,
      this.transactionUserTable.pageIndex + 1,
      this.transactionUserTable.pageSize,
      this.searchTransactionUserInput.nativeElement.value,
      this.transactionUserTable.sortParams,
      this.transactionUserTable.sortDirs
    )
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.isTransactionUserLoading = false)
      )
      .subscribe({
        error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        next: res => {
          console.log("new users"  , this.selectedNewUser)
          this.transactionUserTable.totalElements = res.totalItemCount;
          
          this.transactionUserTable.data = res.items as UserProfileDropdownDto[];
          
          this.totalData = res.totalItemCount;
          this.currentDisplayedData = res.lastItemOnPage;
          res.items.forEach(item => {
            if(item.emailAddress && selectedNewUser.findIndex(x => x.emailAddress === item.emailAddress) !== -1){
              item.checked = true;
            }
          });
        },
        complete: noop
      });
  }
```

#base-model.ts

```
export class BaseModel {
    // createdStr: string;
    // createdByUser: AuditUser;

    // modifiedStr: string;
    // modifiedByUser: AuditUser;
}


export class PagedModel {
firstItemOnPage: boolean;
lastItemOnPage: boolean;
totalItemCount: number;
items: BaseModel[];

constructor(isFirstPage: boolean, isLastPage: boolean, totalItems: number, itemList: BaseModel[]) {
    this.firstItemOnPage = isFirstPage;
    this.lastItemOnPage = isLastPage;
    this.totalItemCount = totalItems;
    this.items = itemList;
}
```

}

#dto user code

```
export class UserProfileDropdownDto {
    id: number;
    fullName: string;
    roleDisplay: string;
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
    isChecked: boolean = false;
}
```

Comment: does `selectedNewUser` model has a property of emailAddress? can you please share it's object data?,

Comment: @SuneelKumar Yes,  I think the problem is with res.items cause even though I will just  res.items.forEach(item => {
            console.log("item.emailAddress" , item.emailAddress)
         
          });

it says Property 'emailAddress' does not exist on type 'BaseModel'.ts(2339)

Comment: Yes, I checked your `BaseModel` above, It's seems like you don't have `emailAddress` in it

Comment: If I add emailAddress  to BaseModel this would be the new error https://imgur.com/a/49VWHAo

Comment: Alright! it's because of type which you applied on `getUserProfileTableDropdown()` as it's response type should be a `Observable<PagedModel>`

Comment: If you focus on `PagedModel` the items property is type of `BaseModel[]`

Comment: can you make it clear Suneel ? what do  you mean ?

Comment: how the problem would be solved

Comment: Okay wait, let me share a solution with you

Comment: Okay @SuneelKumar , I will wait

Comment: I added a answer, Please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, about the behavior of your task, but I assumed that you want to fill a dropdown from API response right?

For that you created this model `UserProfileDropdownDto` & you want to fill this model as an Array from API response, after that you may consume this inside your html,

By Keeping this `scenarios` in my mind, this below solution may help you

Please update your `UserProfileDropdownDto` model like below

```
export class UserProfileDropdownDto extends BaseModel {
    id: number;
    fullName: string;
    roleDisplay: string;
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
    isChecked: boolean = false;
    emailAddress: string;
    ....
}
```

Just make sure that your `UserProfileDropdownDto` model, must has the properties of API response.

Now make correction in your `PagedModel` model like this,

```
export class PagedModel {
  firstItemOnPage: boolean;
  lastItemOnPage: boolean;
  totalItemCount: number;
  items: UserProfileDropdownDto[];

constructor(
  isFirstPage: boolean, 
  isLastPage: boolean, 
  totalItems: number, 
  itemList: UserProfileDropdownDto[]
) {
    this.firstItemOnPage = isFirstPage;
    this.lastItemOnPage = isLastPage;
    this.totalItemCount = totalItems;
    this.items = itemList;
}
```

Comment: You are a legend , thanks for the help and idea Sir.

Comment: By the way last question , why is that I am receiving this error https://imgur.com/a/DiZMYjs on my this.selectedNewUser ?? Sir

Comment: it says Property 'emailAddress' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)

Comment: what's the type of `selectedNewUser` variable? I guess it's type of `BaseModel`

Comment: This is the sample data of https://imgur.com/a/MldPNP5  this.selectedNewUser

Comment: It has Sir , kindly check this data https://imgur.com/a/MldPNP5  , it has emailAddress property

Comment: @Input() selectedNewUser : Array<Object> = [];

Comment: Alright just, change this `@Input() selectedNewUser : Array<Object> = [];` to `@Input() selectedNewUser : Array<any> = [];`

Comment: Thanks , Hello @Suneel , maybe you have idea regarding this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68709106/angular-nested-comparison-of-objects Thanks,

Comment: I checked, & also answered to your question, Please have a look

Comment: Hi @Suneel , do you have idea with this one Sir  ?

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: I describe the issue on the stackblizt link Sir https://stackblitz.com/edit/free-qwm2y6

Comment: Yes, I checked! but what actual problem you are facing?

Comment: I wanted to replace the key id with value 0 and insert memberId key with value equal to the first value of ID before I make it 0

Comment: you need a code to achieve an expected output?

Comment: yes Sir , If you see my sample object on the stackblizt that is the sample data , I need help  how to replace the key id with value 0 and insert memberId key with value equal to the first value of ID before I make it 0

Comment: I wanted to replace the key id with value 0 and insert memberId key with value equal to the first value of ID before I make it 0.

So first get teamMembersDto id value and insert memberId key with value of the id and then replace teamMembersDto id with value equal to 0

Comment: Alright! wait let me write a solution for you!

Comment: Checkout my another answer! I have added now

Answer (score 0):

On Based of your comment! I have write down solution for another problem

**Current Result**

```
let data = {
  "id": 0,
  "name": "adas",
  "description": "dasdas",
  "status": "",
  "teamMembersDto": [
      {
        "id": 120098,
        "fullName": "xsc@gmail.com xsc@gmail.com",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "xsc@gmail.com",
        "lastName": "xsc@gmail.com",
        "emailAddress": "xsc@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "12",
        "companyName": "xsc@gmail.com",
        "title": "xsc@gmail.com",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "09/08/2021 7:44:56 am",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
      },
      {
        "id": 40091,
        "fullName": "yukre@gmail.com yukre@gmail.com",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "yukre@gmail.com",
        "lastName": "yukre@gmail.com",
        "emailAddress": "yukre@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "232423",
        "companyName": "yukre@gmail.com",
        "title": "3434",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "06/08/2021 12:35:32 pm",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
      }
  ],
  "accountId": 4
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
let data = {
  "id": 0,
  "name": "adas",
  "description": "dasdas",
  "status": "",
  "teamMembersDto": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "fullName": "xsc@gmail.com xsc@gmail.com",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "xsc@gmail.com",
        "lastName": "xsc@gmail.com",
        "emailAddress": "xsc@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "12",
        "companyName": "xsc@gmail.com",
        "title": "xsc@gmail.com",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "09/08/2021 7:44:56 am",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null,
        "memberId": 120098
      },
      {
        "id": 0,
        "fullName": "yukre@gmail.com yukre@gmail.com",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "yukre@gmail.com",
        "lastName": "yukre@gmail.com",
        "emailAddress": "yukre@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "232423",
        "companyName": "yukre@gmail.com",
        "title": "3434",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "06/08/2021 12:35:32 pm",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
        "memberId": 40091
      }
  ],
  "accountId": 4
}
```

**Solution**

```
data.teamMembersDto = data.teamMembersDto.map((item) => {
  let id = item.id;
  return {
    ...item,
    id: 0,
    memberId: id
  }
});
```

Comment: your answer is correct Sir , I was wrong I am sorry

Comment: No Problem! you're welcome, plz let me know if you need any help thanks

Comment: Hi @Suneel , do you have idea with this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68753148/angular-mat-select-value-default-value-from-api . Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @JellynAng! Sure, let me check

Comment: @JellynAng! please check my answer