# Angular nested comparison of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Compare selectedNewUser object to res.items object using the emailAddress as key , if match then I want to get or at least log the roles from selectedNewUser that matches the email address.

for example on the data below aaa@gmail.com so the roles is  , but currently the error is Property 'roles' does not exist on type 'any[]'.ts(2339) . Thanks you :).

[image]

#example correct result based on the data below

```
 "roles": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "Architect",
                    "isShow": true,
                    "transactionRoleId": 12
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "Construction Project Director",
                    "isShow": true,
                    "transactionRoleId": 11
                }
            ]
```

#code logic

```
private _transactionUserPageEvent() {
    this.isTransactionUserLoading = true;
    this.transactionUserTable.data = [];
    this._userProfileService.getTeamProfileTableDropdown(
      this.accountId,
      this.transactionUserTable.pageIndex + 1,
      this.transactionUserTable.pageSize,
      this.searchTransactionUserInput.nativeElement.value,
      this.transactionUserTable.sortParams,
      this.transactionUserTable.sortDirs
    )
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.isTransactionUserLoading = false)
      )
      .subscribe({
        error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        next: res => {
          this.transactionUserTable.totalElements = res.totalItemCount;
          this.transactionUserTable.data = res.items as unknown as UserProfileDropdownDto[];
          this.totalData = res.totalItemCount;
          this.currentDisplayedData = res.lastItemOnPage;
          console.log("res" , res.items)
          if(this.selectedNewUser.length !== 0) {
            res.items.forEach(item => {
              if(item.emailAddress && this.selectedNewUser.findIndex(x => x.emailAddress === item.emailAddress) !== -1){
                item.isChecked = true;
                this.userSelectedStatus(item);
                this.appendUserList(true,item)
                this.transactionRoleEvent(this.selectedNewUser.roles, item.id)
                // console.log("itemmmm" , this.selectedNewUser)
              }
            });
          }
        
        },
        complete: noop
      });
  }
```

#selectedNewUser

```
this.selectedNewUser = [
    {
        "emailAddress": "aaa@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "aa",
        "lastName": "aa",
        "phoneNumber": "232",
        "companyName": "bb",
        "title": "CEO",
        "roleId": 7,
        "associatedAccount": "WLGRN",
        "accountId": 4,
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Architect",
                "isShow": true,
                "transactionRoleId": 12
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Construction Project Director",
                "isShow": true,
                "transactionRoleId": 11
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "emailAddress": "bbb@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "bb",
        "lastName": "vv",
        "phoneNumber": "34",
        "companyName": "test",
        "title": "CEO",
        "roleId": 7,
        "associatedAccount": "WLGRN",
        "accountId": 4,
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "Janitor",
                "isShow": true,
                "transactionRoleId": 17
            },
            {
                "id": 18,
                "name": "Project Director",
                "isShow": true,
                "transactionRoleId": 18
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

#res.items data

```
res.items = [
    {
        "id": 120107,
        "fullName": "0 0",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "0",
        "lastName": "0",
        "emailAddress": "aaa@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "0",
        "companyName": "ee",
        "title": "bb",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "09/08/2021 8:18:04 am",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
    },
    {
        "id": 120108,
        "fullName": "0 0",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "0",
        "lastName": "0",
        "emailAddress": "0",
        "phoneNumber": "0",
        "companyName": "0",
        "title": "0",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "09/08/2021 8:19:11 am",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
    },
    {
        "id": 120109,
        "fullName": "0000 0000",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "0000",
        "lastName": "0000",
        "emailAddress": "0000",
        "phoneNumber": "000",
        "companyName": "0000",
        "title": "000",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "09/08/2021 8:19:37 am",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
    },
    {
        "id": 120106,
        "fullName": "1 1",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "1",
        "lastName": "1",
        "emailAddress": "1",
        "phoneNumber": "1",
        "companyName": "1",
        "title": "1",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "09/08/2021 8:16:33 am",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
    },
    {
        "id": 120103,
        "fullName": "111 111",
        "roleDisplay": null,
        "firstName": "111",
        "lastName": "111",
        "emailAddress": "11111@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "111",
        "companyName": "1111",
        "title": "11",
        "lastLogin": null,
        "createdDate": "09/08/2021 8:02:16 am",
        "isVerified": false,
        "roleDto": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "securityRole": "Unlicensed User",
        "lastLoggedIn": "",
        "teamCount": 0,
        "transactionRoleList": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that, the `selectedNewUser` is an Array not a simple Object, you cannot access roles directly from this array `selectedNewUser`. you need to pass the index also like `this.selectedNewUser[0].roles`, but at a moment you haven't think about the `index` of `selectedNewUser`. You need to modified the your `_transactionUserPageEvent()` method like below

```
private _transactionUserPageEvent() {
    this.isTransactionUserLoading = true;
    this.transactionUserTable.data = [];
    this._userProfileService.getTeamProfileTableDropdown(
      this.accountId,
      this.transactionUserTable.pageIndex + 1,
      this.transactionUserTable.pageSize,
      this.searchTransactionUserInput.nativeElement.value,
      this.transactionUserTable.sortParams,
      this.transactionUserTable.sortDirs
    )
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.isTransactionUserLoading = false)
      )
      .subscribe({
        error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        next: res => {
          this.transactionUserTable.totalElements = res.totalItemCount;
          this.transactionUserTable.data = res.items as unknown as UserProfileDropdownDto[];
          this.totalData = res.totalItemCount;
          this.currentDisplayedData = res.lastItemOnPage;
          console.log("res" , res.items)
          if(this.selectedNewUser.length !== 0) {
            res.items.forEach(item => {
              
              if(item.emailAddress){
                let index = this.selectedNewUser.findIndex(x => x.emailAddress === item.emailAddress); // getting index separately 
                if(index !== -1) {
                   item.isChecked = true;
                   this.userSelectedStatus(item);
                   this.appendUserList(true,item)
                   //this.transactionRoleEvent(this.selectedNewUser.roles, item.id)
                this.transactionRoleEvent(this.selectedNewUser[index].roles, item.id) // this will work for you
                  // console.log("itemmmm" , this.selectedNewUser)
                }
                
              }
            });
          }
        
        },
        complete: noop
      });
  }
```

Hope it may help you

Comment: Again modified little bit