# Angular mat select value default value from api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do we set the default value to a select menu in the latest angular? I have `getAccountRoleDropdown` that gets the list of roles and populates it to a select menu, I also have `getUserGeneralDetails` that get the details of users.

I want to check if the `userRoleDto` from `getUserGeneralDetails` has value then show it as default value (value is the id), show `roleName` on `mat-select` and show `accountRoles` as options and if a user wanted select item from mat select options set value as id and show roleName.

Any idea on how is this possible guys? do I still need `selectChangeHandler`? Thanks.

#html code for the select

```html
   <mat-select (selectionChange)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let role of accountRoles" >
         {{role.roleName}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

#user data from getUsergeneraldetails

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "invitedByDate": "08/10/2021 02:06 am",
    "identityId": null,
    "title": "COO",
    "isSso": null,
    "ssocredentials": "",
    "userAccountDto": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "accountId": 4,
            "userRoleDto": {
                "id": 6,
                "roleName": "Transaction Super User"
            },
    ],
    "accountId": 0,
    "roleId": 6,
    "isVerified": null,
    "securityRole": "Transaction Super User",
    "ssoEnabled": "No",
   
}
```

#get user data

```js
getUserGeneralDetails() {
    this.isInProgress = true;
    this._userProfileService
      .getUserGeneralDetails(this.userId, this.accountId)
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isInProgress = false)))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          if (res.isSuccess) {
            this.data = res.data;
            console.log("user data" , this.data)
          }
        },
        error: (err) => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        complete: noop,
      });
  }
```

[image]

#accountRoles Object from getAccountRoleDropdown

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "roleName": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "roleName": "Broker"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "roleName": "Transaction Manager"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "roleName": "Transaction Super User"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "roleName": "Unlicensed User"
    }
]
```

#get list of roles

```
getAccountRoleDropdown() {
    this.AccountRoleIsInProgress = true;
     this._accountService.getAccountRoleDropdown(this.accountId, "")
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.AccountRoleIsInProgress = false),
      ).subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          if (res.isSuccess) {
            this.accountRoles = res.data;
            console.log("this.accountRoles" ,this.accountRoles)
            // this.populateAccountRoleDropdown(res.data);
          }
        },
        error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        complete: noop
      });
  }
```

Comment: you need add [value]="role.id" to your options, and use template driven forms (ngModel) or ReactiveForms instead  of use (selectionChange)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using **ngModel**, I have modified your code, `(HTML & TYPESCRIPT)` please have a look below:

**component.ts**

```
generalUserDetails: any;
  accountRoles: Array<any> = [];
  defaultRole: any; // save your default in this variable

  constructor() {
    this.generalUserDetails = {
      "id": 1,
      "invitedByDate": "08/10/2021 02:06 am",
      "identityId": null,
      "title": "COO",
      "isSso": null,
      "ssocredentials": "",
      "userAccountDto": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "accountId": 4,
          "userRoleDto": {
            "id": 6,
            "roleName": "Transaction Super User"
          }
        }
      ],
      "accountId": 0,
      "roleId": 6,
      "isVerified": null,
      "securityRole": "Transaction Super User",
      "ssoEnabled": "No",
    };
    this.accountRoles = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "roleName": "Admin"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "roleName": "Broker"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "roleName": "Transaction Manager"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "roleName": "Transaction Super User"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "roleName": "Unlicensed User"
      }
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDefaultRole();
  }

  // this method will help you to get default role
  getDefaultRole() {
    if(this.generalUserDetails && this.accountRoles.length) {
      let role = this.accountRoles.find(o=>o.id == this.generalUserDetails.userAccountDto[0].userRoleDto?.id);
      if(role) {
        this.defaultRole = role;
      }
    }
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="defaultRole" (selectionChange)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let role of accountRoles" [value]="role">
      {{role.roleName}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>You selected: {{defaultRole | json}}</p>
```

**Screenshot with Output**
[image]

**Note:** Please don't forget to import `FormsModule` in your app.module

Currently I hardcoded the `user Details Data`, & `account roles` but you need to consume already defined method `getUserGeneralDetails()` & `getAccountRoleDropdown()` respectively

**Solution with ReactiveForm**

**HTML CODE**

```
<form [formGroup]="securityForm" class="securityForm">

  <label class="label1">Assign Security Role (*)</label>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [formControl]="roleId" (selectionChange)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let role of accountRoles" [value]="role.id">
        {{role.roleName}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  
</form>
```

**.TS CODE**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  AccountRoleIsInProgress: boolean = false;
  accountRoles: Array<any> = [];

  isInProgress: boolean = false;
  data: any;

  securityForm: FormGroup;
  isSso: FormControl;
  ssocredentials: FormControl;
  roleId: FormControl;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.isSso = new FormControl();
    this.ssocredentials = new FormControl();
    this.roleId = new FormControl();

    this.securityForm = this.fb.group({
      isSso: this.isSso,
      ssocredentials: this.ssocredentials,
      roleId: this.roleId
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUserGeneralDetails();
    this.getAccountRoleDropdown();
    this.getDefaultRole();
  }

  getAccountRoleDropdown() {
    // this.AccountRoleIsInProgress = true;
    // this._accountService
    //   .getAccountRoleDropdown(this.accountId, '')
    //   .pipe(finalize(() => (this.AccountRoleIsInProgress = false)))
    //   .subscribe({
    //     next: res => {
    //       if (res.isSuccess) {
    //         this.accountRoles = res.data;
    //         console.log('this.accountRoles', this.accountRoles);
    //         // this.populateAccountRoleDropdown(res.data);
    //       }
    //     },
    //     error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
    //     complete: noop
    //   });
    return [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "roleName": "Admin"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "roleName": "Broker"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "roleName": "Transaction Manager"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "roleName": "Transaction Super User"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "roleName": "Unlicensed User"
      }
    ];
  }

  getUserGeneralDetails() {
    // this.isInProgress = true;
    // this._userProfileService
    //   .getUserGeneralDetails(this.userId, this.accountId)
    //   .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isInProgress = false)))
    //   .subscribe({
    //     next: res => {
    //       if (res.isSuccess) {
    //         this.data = res.data;
    //         console.log('user data', this.data);
    //       }
    //     },
    //     error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
    //     complete: noop
    //   });

    return {
      "id": 1,
      "invitedByDate": "08/10/2021 02:06 am",
      "identityId": null,
      "title": "COO",
      "isSso": null,
      "ssocredentials": "",
      "userAccountDto": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "accountId": 4,
          "userRoleDto": {
            "id": 6,
            "roleName": "Transaction Super User"
          }
        }
      ],
      "accountId": 0,
      "roleId": 6,
      "isVerified": null,
      "securityRole": "Transaction Super User",
      "ssoEnabled": "No",
    };
  }

  // this method will help you to get default role
  getDefaultRole() {
    if(this.data && this.accountRoles.length) {
      let role = this.accountRoles.find(o=>o.id == this.data.userAccountDto[0].userRoleDto?.id);
      if(role) {
        this.roleId.setValue(role.id);
      }
    }
  }

  selectChangeHandler(event) {
    
  }
}
```

**Note:** Note: Please don't forget to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `app.module.ts`

Comment: Hi @Sunnel , I got an error core.js:6162 ERROR Error: 
      ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:

      
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()

Comment: Oh! you are consuming reactive form right? so ngModel may not work in this way, any way have you create a form control for this select dropdown??

Comment: If possible, please share you code with me using this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jvmkvc

Comment: If I assume, that you have this formControl for your `mat-select` element `accountRole: FormControl`, that instead of using `[(ngModel)]`, you can use formControl like this '[formControl]="accountRole"' & also in your `.ts` file within the method of `getDefaultRole()` set value of formControl like this `this.accountRole.setValue(role)`

Comment: @Sunnel https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8rbi98

Comment: @JellynAng! I edit my answer provide new solution with reactiveForm as well, please try that approach, now it may resolve your issue

Comment: Hi Sir , it it possible that we pass [value]="role" using ReactiveForm? while the select menu still show the default value ? cause I need to pass the whole object to selectChangeHandler to get the roleName , If I only pass [value]="role.id" then I cant get the roleName . Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can! actually your `formControl` name is `roleId`, so, I thought you just want to keep Id, you can assign the role to value attribute like this `[value]="role"` & also make the change of this line `roleId.setValue(role.id)` to `roleId.setValue(role)` in your `component.ts` file

Comment: If I do [value]="role"  , how do we show the default selected value on the dropdown ? since role is an object

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8rbi98 , please check this Sir

Comment: How do I get the roleName based on the select menu current selected ID?

Comment: You can show `roleName` from `role` object like this `{{role.roleName}}`,

Comment: currently your code may not fill the default value of role, because this method `getDefaultRole()` is called before initialization of `this.data && this.accountRoles`, So, I will suggest you kindly call this method, within `getUserGeneralDetails()` & also within this `getAccountRoleDropdown()`

Comment: Hi Sir , thanks for this answer. I have another question Sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68776721/angular-child-component-table , Maybe you have idea with this one.

Comment: Hi @JellynAng! thanks for new question, let me check!

Comment: @JellynAng! please check my answer

Comment: Also checkout my answer to  this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68779927/how-to-define-nested-object-model-in-angular

Comment: Hi @Suneel , do you have idea with this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68797290/insert-data-to-nested-form-data-object

Comment: Hi @JellynAng! Yes let me provide you a solution,

Comment: @JellynAng! Please checkout my answer

Comment: Thanks for that @Suneel , By the way Sir , do you have idea how to implement this one ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68820282/angular-converting-names-to-initials-inside-avatar