# Angular child component Table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 component which is Component A and B , in component A I called a child component which is Component B which is a table the app-team-management selector(child component).

If I switch tab to Teams it should render the child component which is app-team-management. Right now it was able to render child component's front-end but it was not able to render the child component data , the app-team-management was called but the it did not render the data. The ngOnInit of app-team-management did not also rendered or called

I also added a console log to ngOnInit of child component which is the app-team-management but the
ngOnInit did not initialize

What seem to be the problem with the code ? why is that when I call the child component app-team-management it did not render the data or even call the ngOnInit  ? . Thanks for any help and suggestions. Appreciated.

#Component A HTML

```
 <div headerTabs class="v-bg-color-3">
        <mat-tab-group
          animationDuration="0ms"
          #tabGroup
          (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)"
        >
          <mat-tab label="Users">

            <div class="mat-tab-shadow-container">
              <div class="mat-tab-shadow"></div>
              <div class="tab-content">
          </mat-tab>

          <mat-tab label="Teams">

            <div class="mat-tab-shadow-container">
              <div class="mat-tab-shadow"></div>
              <div class="tab-content">

               <app-team-management [resetFormSubject]="resetFormSubject"></app-team-management>
               
              </div>
            </div>

          </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
      </div>
    </app-page-header>
  </div>
```

#Component A switch tab ts code

```
 tabChanged(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
    this.currentTab = tabChangeEvent.index;
    if(this.currentTab !== 1) {
      this.pageHeaderTitleData.title.primary = "Users"
      this._pageEventMyList();
    }
    this.pageHeaderTitleData.title.primary = "Teams"
  }
```

#Component B child component app-team-management code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-team-management',
  templateUrl: './team-management.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./team-management.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  animations: velocityAnimations
})
export class TeamManagementComponent implements OnInit {
  teamTable: TableData<TeamMembersDropdownDto>;
  @Input() resetFormSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  stateModel = new StateModel();
  filterFormControl: any;
  @ViewChild(MatMultiSort, { static: true }) sort: MatMultiSort;
  @ViewChild('searchInput') searchInput: ElementRef;
  CLIENT_SIDE = false;accountId: any;
  isLoading: boolean;
  totalData: number;
  currentDisplayedData: any;

  constructor(private _notificationService: NotificationService,private _teamService: TeamService,private router: Router,) { 
    this.teamTable = new TableData<TeamMembersDropdownDto>(
      [
        { id: 'name', name: 'name' },
        { id: 'description', name: 'description' },
        { id: 'members', name: 'members' },
        { id: 'transactions', name: 'transactions' },
      ], { defaultSortParams: ['name'], defaultSortDirs: ['asc'] }
    );

    this.teamTable.pageSize = 10;
    this.teamTable.pageIndex = 0;

    this.filterFormControl = new FormGroup({
      filters: new FormControl('1') 
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    console.log("render here")

    this.resetFormSubject.subscribe(response => {
      if(response){
        console.log("fdgdfgfd")
    }
   })
    const currentAccountDetails = localStorage.getItem('currAcct') as any;
    if (currentAccountDetails) {
      this.accountId = JSON.parse(currentAccountDetails).accountId;
    }
    
    this.teamTable.dataSource = new MatMultiSortTableDataSource(this.sort, this.CLIENT_SIDE);
    this.teamTable.nextObservable.subscribe(() => { this._tableEvent(); });
    this.teamTable.sortObservable.subscribe(() => { this._tableEvent(); });
    this.teamTable.previousObservable.subscribe(() => { this._tableEvent(); });
    this.teamTable.sizeObservable.subscribe(() => { this._tableEvent(); });
    // this._getPageCount();
  }

  private _tableEvent() {
    console.log("test")
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.teamTable.data = [];
    this._teamService.getTeamProfileTableDropdown(
      this.accountId,
      this.teamTable.pageIndex + 1,
      this.teamTable.pageSize,
      this.searchInput.nativeElement.value,
      this.teamTable.sortParams,
      this.teamTable.sortDirs
    )
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.isLoading = false)
      )
      .subscribe({
        error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        next: res => {
          this.teamTable.totalElements = res.totalItemCount;
          this.totalData = res.totalItemCount;
          this.currentDisplayedData = res.lastItemOnPage;
          this.teamTable.data = res.items as TeamMembersDropdownDto[];
          console.log("res.items" , res.items)
        },
        complete: noop
      });
  }
  viewTeamsDetails(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['settings/user/editteam'],
      {
        queryParams: { id: id }
      });
  }
}
```

#child component HTML code

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 22vh;">
    <div fxLayout="column" style="padding: 32px;">
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="16px">
        <div style="padding-right: 16px;">
          <span class="table-info"
            >Showing {{currentDisplayedData}} of {{totalData}} of
            Teams</span
          >
        </div>
        <div [formGroup]="filterFormControl">
          <mat-radio-group
            aria-label="Select an option"
            formControlName="filters"
          >
            <mat-radio-button value="1" style="padding-right: 32px;"
              >Active
            </mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button *ifRoles="[]" value="2"
              >Archived teams (3)</mat-radio-button
            >
          </mat-radio-group>
        </div>
      </div>
      <mat-card fxLayout="column" class="users-table-list">
        <div fxLayout="column" class="users-list">
          <div fxLayout="column">
            <div fxLayout="column">
              <div
                class="table"
                [ngStyle.gt-md]="{'overflow': 'auto'}"
              >
                <div fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                  <mat-form-field
                    appearance="standard"
                    class="users-list-filter"
                  >
                    <mat-label style="font-size:12px"
                      >Search in Teams
                    </mat-label>
                    <input matInput #searchInput placeholder="" />
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <mat-table
                  [dataSource]="teamTable.dataSource"
                  [@animateStagger]="{value:'50'}"
                  matMultiSort
                  (matSortChange)="teamTable.onSortEvent()"
                >
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                    <mat-header-cell
                      *matHeaderCellDef
                      fxHide
                      fxShow.gt-xs
                      fxShow.gt-md
                      mat-multi-sort-header="name"
                      class="users-table-header"
                    >
                      Team Name
                    </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell
                      *matCellDef="let item"
                      fxHide
                      fxShow.gt-xs
                      fxShow.gt-md
                    >
                      {{item.name}}
                    </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
                    <mat-header-cell
                      *matHeaderCellDef
                      fxHide
                      fxShow.gt-xs
                      fxShow.gt-md
                      mat-multi-sort-header="description"
                      class="users-table-header"
                    >
                      Team Description
                    </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell
                      *matCellDef="let item"
                      fxHide
                      fxShow.gt-xs
                      fxShow.gt-md
                    >
                      {{item.description || 'None'}}
                    </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="members">
                    <mat-header-cell
                      *matHeaderCellDef
                      fxHide
                      fxShow.gt-xs
                      fxShow.gt-md
                      mat-multi-sort-header="members"
                      class="users-table-header"
                    >
                      Members
                    </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell
                      *matCellDef="let item"
                      fxHide
                      fxShow.gt-xs
                      fxShow.gt-md
                    >
                      <div
                        *ngFor="let member of item.teamMembersDto;let isLast=last"
                      >
                        {{member.firstName}}{{isLast ? '' : ','}}
                      </div>
                    </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="transactions">
                    <mat-header-cell
                      *matHeaderCellDef
                      fxHide
                      fxShow.gt-xs
                      fxShow.gt-md
                      mat-multi-sort-header="transactions"
                      class="users-table-header"
                    >
                      Transactions
                    </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell
                      *matCellDef="let item"
                      fxHide
                      fxShow.gt-xs
                      fxShow.gt-md
                    >
                      <div>
                        in
                        {{ item.teamTransactionDetailsDto.length}}
                        transactions
                      </div>
                    </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>

                  <mat-header-row
                    *matHeaderRowDef="teamTable.displayedColumns; sticky:true"
                    style="padding-bottom: 16px;"
                  >
                  </mat-header-row>
                  <mat-row
                    (click)="viewTeamsDetails(item.id)"
                    *matRowDef="let item; columns: teamTable.displayedColumns;"
                    [ngClass]="{'active': stateModel.id === item.id}"
                  >
                  </mat-row>
                </mat-table>
                <mat-progress-bar
                  *ngIf="isLoading"
                  mode="indeterminate"
                ></mat-progress-bar>
                <div
                  class="no-record"
                  *ngIf="!isLoading && teamTable.totalElements == 0"
                >
                  No Teams
                </div>

                <mat-paginator
                  fxLayoutAlign="end start"
                  [pageSize]="teamTable.pageSize"
                  [pageIndex]="teamTable.pageIndex"
                  [pageSizeOptions]="teamTable.pageSizeOptions"
                  [length]="teamTable.totalElements ? teamTable.totalElements : 0"
                  (page)="teamTable.onPaginationEvent($event)"
                  [disabled]="CLIENT_SIDE"
                  showFirstLastButtons
                >
                </mat-paginator>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: `app-team-management` is the child component and `ngOnInit` is not firing? no errors?

Comment: Yeah , it did not even log the console log I put , but it rendered the template as you see on the screenshot

Comment: but when I change the items per page or click the sort in loads the data , but at first or at initialization it did not load the data Sir

Answer (score 0):

Mat tab usually preloads all components, meaning your ngOnInit should be triggered way before you click on second tab.
it could mean that it's trying to get data which doesn't yet exist.
I would first try to lazy load your child component by adding ng-template, that should fix onInit runing when you click on tab.

```
 <mat-tab label="Teams">
     <div class="mat-tab-shadow-container">
        <div class="mat-tab-shadow"></div>
           <div class="tab-content">
              <ng-template>
               <app-team-management [resetFormSubject]="resetFormSubject"></app-team-management>
              </ng-template>
              </div>
            </div>
          </mat-tab>
```

Second, I would put this code

```
this.teamTable.dataSource = new MatMultiSortTableDataSource(this.sort, this.CLIENT_SIDE);
this.teamTable.nextObservable.subscribe(() => { this._tableEvent(); });
this.teamTable.sortObservable.subscribe(() => { this._tableEvent(); });
this.teamTable.previousObservable.subscribe(() => { this._tableEvent(); });
this.teamTable.sizeObservable.subscribe(() => { this._tableEvent(); });
```

into AfterViewInit, since it depends on ViewChild, or put setter in ViewChild to trigger when html loads.

Comment: I tried this answer Sir but it did not solve the problem , also with these solution the template did not even render, there are no error also I checked the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to understand the `angular life cycle fellow`, after reviewing you're code, I analyzed that you depending on execution of `ngOnInit()` method, but unfortunately it's not happen right? this is because of `Angular Life Cycle fellow`, the method `ngOnInit()` is just executed once when component is loaded,

So in your case, you need to implement another `angular life cycle method` which is `OnChanges`, Once you implement with your component, It will force you to override it's `ngOnChange(change: SimpleChanges)` method, like Below

[image]

Whenever you switch the tab, this `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)` method will execute, for that you need to pass the data to child component.

It Seems you are not passing data to child component! may be you have global data or you are fetching data from api within child component, not sure!

Can you please let me know, how did you getting the data for child component?