# How to define nested object model in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Property `roleDto` does not exist on type `TeamMembersDropdownDto[]`. Cause I wanted to assign the `this.model.teamMembersDto.roleDto` to `teamMembersDto` as you can see below. The `roleDto` array of object us under `teamMembersDto`.

But it gives me the error above that `roleDto` does not exist on type `TeamMembersDropdownDto[]`, but since it is nested how do I add the `roleDto` to `TeamMembersDropdownDto[]` or `TeamDto` that it should be under `teamMembersDto`? Thanks for any replies.

#data

```
[
  {
    "id": 10011,
    "name": "TESTING TEAM",
    "description": "THE TEST TEAM",
    "memberCount": 2,
    "accountId": 4,
    "status": "Active",
    "createOnString": null,
    "teamMembersDto": [
      {
        "id": 10017,
        "firstName": "Alexa",
        "lastName": "Ryan",
        "title": "COO",
        "memberId": 1,
        "roleDto": [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "COVP",
            "isShow": true,
            "transactionRoleId": 9
          },
          {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "DVP Real Estate",
            "isShow": true,
            "transactionRoleId": 6
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 10018,
        "firstName": "Briana",
        "lastName": "Christoval",
        "title": null,
        "memberId": 2,
        "roleDto": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Architect",
            "isShow": true,
            "transactionRoleId": 12
          },
          {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Construction Project Director",
            "isShow": true,
            "transactionRoleId": 11
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "teamTransactionDetailsDto": []
  },
]
```

#dto model code

```js
export class TeamDto {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  accountId: string;
  status: string;
  teamMembersDto: TeamMembersDropdownDto[];
  teamTransactionDetailsDto: TeamTransactionDetailsDto[];
}
```

#main component code

```js
import { TeamDto } from 'src/app/core/models/teams/team-dropdown-dto'
model = new TeamDto();

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getTeamGeneralDetails();
}

getTeamGeneralDetails() {
  this.isInProgress = true;
  this._teamService
    .getTeamsGeneralDetails(this.teamId)
    .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isInProgress = false)))
    .subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        if (res.isSuccess) {

          this.model = res.data
          this.membersForm = this._createModelForm();

        }
      },
      error: (err) => this._notificationService.showError(err),
      complete: noop,
    });
}
    
 private _createModelForm(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    id: [this.model.id || 0],
    teamMembersDto: [this.model.teamMembersDto.roleDto || []],
    teamTransactionDetailsDto: [this.model.teamTransactionDetailsDto || []]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

As a reference to @Ramesh's answer, you can `flat` the array to get `roleDto` from `teamMembersDto` as below:

```js
private _createModelForm(): FormGroup {
  const roles = this.model.teamMembersDto.reduce(
    (teamMembers, member) => [...teamMembers, ...member.roleDto],
    []
  );

  console.log("Roles: ", roles);

  return this.fb.group({
    id: [this.model.id || 0],
    teamMembersDto: [roles || []],
    teamTransactionDetailsDto: [this.model.teamTransactionDetailsDto || []]
  });
}
```

---

### Solution 2

Alternative, you can do with **(reduce and concat)** way as well:

```js
private _createModelForm(): FormGroup {
  const rolesByTeam = this.model.teamMembersDto.map(teamMember => {
    return teamMember.roleDto.reduce((roles, role) => roles.concat(role), []);
  });

  const roles = rolesByTeam.reduce((arr, role) => arr.concat(role), []);

  console.log("Roles by team: ", rolesByTeam);
  console.log("Roles: ", roles);

  return this.fb.group({
    id: [this.model.id || 0],
    teamMembersDto: [roles || []],
    teamTransactionDetailsDto: [this.model.teamTransactionDetailsDto || []]
  });
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ndetmh)

---

### References

[Array.prototype.flat() (Reduce and concat section)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 1):

If we want all the roles available for the given team, we could reduce them as below.

```
const roles = data.reduce(
  (teamRoles, team) =>
    team.teamMembersDto.reduce(
      (memberRoles, member) => [...memberRoles, ...member.roleDto],
      teamRoles
    ),
  []
);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to get `roleDto[]` from `teamMembersDto[]` which currently present inside the `Array of data[]` right? please checkout this solution

```
let data = [
  {
    id: 10011,
    name: 'TESTING TEAM',
    description: 'THE TEST TEAM',
    memberCount: 2,
    accountId: 4,
    status: 'Active',
    createOnString: null,
    teamMembersDto: [
      {
        id: 10017,
        firstName: 'Alexa',
        lastName: 'Ryan',
        title: 'COO',
        memberId: 1,
        roleDto: [
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'COVP',
            isShow: true,
            transactionRoleId: 9
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            name: 'DVP Real Estate',
            isShow: true,
            transactionRoleId: 6
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 10018,
        firstName: 'Briana',
        lastName: 'Christoval',
        title: null,
        memberId: 2,
        roleDto: [
          {
            id: 8,
            name: 'Architect',
            isShow: true,
            transactionRoleId: 12
          },
          {
            id: 9,
            name: 'Construction Project Director',
            isShow: true,
            transactionRoleId: 11
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    teamTransactionDetailsDto: []
  }
];


let roleDto = data[0].teamMembersDto.map((item) => item.roleDto);
console.log(roleDto) // It will be an array of roleDto
```

In your component code you created variable like this `model = new TeamDto();`, It seems tihs model will be single `Object` not an `Array`, however you're data is one kind of `array` not an `object`

**#data**

```
[
  {
    "id": 10011,
    "name": "TESTING TEAM",
    "description": "THE TEST TEAM",
    "memberCount": 2,
    "accountId": 4,
    "status": "Active",
    "createOnString": null,
    "teamMembersDto": [
      {
        "id": 10017,
        "firstName": "Alexa",
        "lastName": "Ryan",
        "title": "COO",
        "memberId": 1,
        "roleDto": [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "COVP",
            "isShow": true,
            "transactionRoleId": 9
          },
          {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "DVP Real Estate",
            "isShow": true,
            "transactionRoleId": 6
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 10018,
        "firstName": "Briana",
        "lastName": "Christoval",
        "title": null,
        "memberId": 2,
        "roleDto": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Architect",
            "isShow": true,
            "transactionRoleId": 12
          },
          {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Construction Project Director",
            "isShow": true,
            "transactionRoleId": 11
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "teamTransactionDetailsDto": []
  },
]
```

I Believed that the data which you are getting inside the `getTeamGeneralDetails()` is an `Object` not an `Array`,

**So in case of `Object` the solution of above problem will be like this**

```
let data = {
    id: 10011,
    name: 'TESTING TEAM',
    description: 'THE TEST TEAM',
    memberCount: 2,
    accountId: 4,
    status: 'Active',
    createOnString: null,
    teamMembersDto: [
      {
        id: 10017,
        firstName: 'Alexa',
        lastName: 'Ryan',
        title: 'COO',
        memberId: 1,
        roleDto: [
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'COVP',
            isShow: true,
            transactionRoleId: 9
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            name: 'DVP Real Estate',
            isShow: true,
            transactionRoleId: 6
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 10018,
        firstName: 'Briana',
        lastName: 'Christoval',
        title: null,
        memberId: 2,
        roleDto: [
          {
            id: 8,
            name: 'Architect',
            isShow: true,
            transactionRoleId: 12
          },
          {
            id: 9,
            name: 'Construction Project Director',
            isShow: true,
            transactionRoleId: 11
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    teamTransactionDetailsDto: []
  };


let roleDto = data.teamMembersDto.map((item) => item.roleDto);
console.log(roleDto) // It will be an array of roleDto
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(let item of this.model.teamMembersDto) {
  for(let item1 of item.roleDto) {
    here you can access the roleDto
```