# insert new key data and value to an array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanted to insert account Id to the this.membersForm.value object , and on the this.membersForm.value.teamMembersDto object I wanna set id to 0 and add memberId : id

how do we insert for example accountId key and value to the object ? please see exptectedOutput

What seem to be the issue on the code ?

#myCode

```
const accountId = this.data.accountId

    this.membersForm.value.teamMembersDto = this.membersForm.value.teamMembersDto.map((item) => {
          let id = item.id;
          return {
            ...item,
            memberId: id,
            id: 0,  
          }
        });
```

#original data

```
 this.membersForm.value =  {
        "id": 10011,
        "teamMembersDto": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "firstName": "Marthy",
                "lastName": "Hills",
                "roleDisplay": "COVP,DVP Real Estate",
                "companyName": "Techmo",
                "title": "COO",
  
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "firstName": "Briana",
                "lastName": "Christoval",
                "roleDisplay": "Architect,Construction Project Director",
                "companyName": null,
                "title": null,
            }
        ]
    }
```

#exptectedOutput

```
{
    "id": 10011,
    "accountId:" 4,
    "teamMembersDto": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "firstName": "Marthy",
            "lastName": "Hills",
            "roleDisplay": "COVP,DVP Real Estate",
            "companyName": "Techmo",
            "title": "COO",
            "memberId": 1,
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "firstName": "Briana",
            "lastName": "Christoval",
            "roleDisplay": "Architect,Construction Project Director",
            "companyName": null,
            "title": null,
            "memberId": 2,
        },

    ]
}
```

___________________second question

#data

```
{
    "id": 20018,
    "name": "yoyo",
    "description": "yoyoyo",
    "memberCount": 2,
    "accountId": 4,
    "status": "Active",
    "createOnString": null,
    "teamMembersDto": [
        {
            "id": 10090,
            "firstName": "ADASDAD@gmail.com",
            "lastName": "ADASDAD@gmail.com",
            "roleDisplay": "Architect,Construction Project Director",
            "companyName": "ADASDAD@gmail.com",
            "title": null,
            "memberId": 10090,
            "roleDto": [
                {
                    "id": 10064,
                    "name": "Architect",
                    "isShow": true,
                    "transactionRoleId": 12
                },
                {
                    "id": 10065,
                    "name": "Construction Project Director",
                    "isShow": true,
                    "transactionRoleId": 11
                }
            ],
            "fullName": "ADASDAD@gmail.com ADASDAD@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 10088,
            "firstName": "adasdas",
            "lastName": "dasdas",
            "roleDisplay": "Architect,Construction Project Director",
            "companyName": "cc",
            "title": "ceo",
            "memberId": 10088,
            "roleDto": [
                {
                    "id": 10066,
                    "name": "Architect",
                    "isShow": true,
                    "transactionRoleId": 12
                },
                {
                    "id": 10067,
                    "name": "Construction Project Director",
                    "isShow": true,
                    "transactionRoleId": 11
                }
            ],
            "fullName": "adasdas dasdas"
        }
    ],
    "teamTransactionDetailsDto": []
}
```

#exptectOutput

```
{
    "id": 20018,
    "name": "yoyo",
    "description": "yoyoyo",
    "memberCount": 2,
    "accountId": 4,
    "status": "Active",
    "createOnString": null,
    "teamMembersDto": [
        {
            "id": 10090,
            "firstName": "ADASDAD@gmail.com",
            "lastName": "ADASDAD@gmail.com",
            "roleDisplay": "Architect,Construction Project Director",
            "companyName": "ADASDAD@gmail.com",
            "title": null,
            "memberId": 10090,
            "roleDto": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "Architect",
                    "isShow": true,
                    "transactionRoleId": 12
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Construction Project Director",
                    "isShow": true,
                    "transactionRoleId": 11
                }
            ],
            "fullName": "ADASDAD@gmail.com ADASDAD@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 10088,
            "firstName": "adasdas",
            "lastName": "dasdas",
            "roleDisplay": "Architect,Construction Project Director",
            "companyName": "cc",
            "title": "ceo",
            "memberId": 10088,
            "roleDto": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "Architect",
                    "isShow": true,
                    "transactionRoleId": 12
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "Construction Project Director",
                    "isShow": true,
                    "transactionRoleId": 11
                }
            ],
            "fullName": "adasdas dasdas"
        }
    ],
    "teamTransactionDetailsDto": []
}
```

Comment: Are you using any state management libraries, like NGRx?  Is that data being managed in the state management?  I have had this happen and you have to set the object within statement

Comment: No , it is just a membersForm: FormGroup;

Comment: do you get any kind of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have write down a simple script for you, it may help you, please have a look below

```js
let data = {
  "id": 10011,
  "teamMembersDto": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "Marthy",
      "lastName": "Hills",
      "roleDisplay": "COVP,DVP Real Estate",
      "companyName": "Techmo",
      "title": "COO",
    },
    {
       "id": 2,
       "firstName": "Briana",
       "lastName": "Christoval",
       "roleDisplay": "Architect,Construction Project Director",
       "companyName": null,
       "title": null,
     }
   ]
}

data["accountId"] = 0 // this will add new 

data.teamMembersDto = data.teamMembersDto.map((item) => {
  let id = item.id;
  return {
    ...item,
    memberId: id, 
    id: 0
  }
});
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Sir , I have second question above , how do we replace teamMembersDto.roleDto.id with teamMembersDto.roleDto.trasactionId value ? . I posted expected output above. Thank you,

Comment: I want to map  data.teamMembersDto like what you did above and also map data.teamMembersDto.roleDto in once code without seperating it.

Comment: Hi @JellynAng, I post another answer, please have a look

Comment: Hi @JellynAng, I again modified my second answer, please have a look