# Angular converting names to initials inside avatar

Tags: angular, typescript

How do we convert names to initials and put in like a circle icon with the initial inside like on the screenshot below , I already have the code that converts the initials , now how do we create and add it inside icons ? and the max display would be 4 icon as you can see on the screenshot and then the remaining count would be added inside the icon.

#right now this is my current output , it display the list of names but I wanted to convert like icons on the screenshot below like some line-avatar, Any idea guys ? Thanks.

#code to get initials

```
const fullName = nameString.split(' ');
const initials = fullName.shift().charAt(0) + fullName.pop().charAt(0);
return initials.toUpperCase();
```

#table code to display  the names

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="members">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef fxHide fxShow.gt-xs fxShow.gt-md mat-multi-sort-header="members"
                    class="users-table-header">
                    Members
                  </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" fxHide fxShow.gt-xs fxShow.gt-md>
                    <div *ngFor="let member of item.teamMembersDto;let isLast=last">
                      {{member.firstName}} {{member.lastName}}{{isLast ? '' : ','}}
                    </div>
                  </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
```

[image: louiseking2035]

Comment: are you trying to display the given name is circular icon with Initials ?

Comment: yes Sir , that is right , including the distance

Comment: ok , let me check

Comment: You might want to try name.split(" ")[0][0] and name.split(" ")[1][0] to get the initials. Rest is done with css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's create the structures required for the names using HTML and CSS

```
<div class="rows">
<div class="circles" *ngFor='let item of names; let i = index'>
  {{ i +1  < 4  ? getInitials(item , i) : '+'  +  (names.length - i) }}
</div>
</div>
```

for the css part

```
   .rows {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.circles{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #eee;
  border : 2px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  
}
.rows .circles:not(:first-child) {
margin-left: -18px;
}
.rows .circles:nth-child(n+5){
   display: none;
  }
```

For ts

```
    names = ['richard rick' , 'alphonse dave' , 'kilin mbappe' , 'brock lesnae' , 'kane wills' , 'Mark angel' , 'astro boy']


  getInitials(nameString , i){
    const fullName = nameString.split(' ');
const initials = fullName.shift().charAt(0) + fullName.pop().charAt(0);
return initials.toUpperCase();
  }
```

here is a stack blitz demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hkd8uj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Invalid stakblitz link

Comment: Dont call methods like getInitials from template. Especially in *ngFor.  It will be called a LOT of times. Instead create the property on the model using for instance rxjs pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Faizal Hussain you could optimise the code performance because you should not call a function direcly in the template

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  names = [
    'richard rick',
    'alphonse dave',
    'kilin mbappe',
    'brock lesnae',
    'kane wills',
    'Mark angel',
    'astro boy',
  ];

  initials = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getInitials();
  }

  getInitials(): void {
    this.names.forEach((name) => {
      const fullName = name.split(' ');
      const initials = fullName.shift().charAt(0) + fullName.pop().charAt(0);
      initials.toUpperCase();
      this.initials.push(initials);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rows">
  <div class="circles" *ngFor="let initial of initials; let i = index">
    {{ i + 1 < 4 ? initial : '+' + (initials.length - i) }}
  </div>
</div>
```